# Show only tasks referred to me on Tasks application

Tags: tasks, task-assignment

I created Tasks Application on `Settings -> Add an app`

[image]

and added it as webpart. Now, I want to see only Tasks directly assigned to me.

Any idea how to do that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a view for the list and filter with the condition  **Assigned By is equal to [me].**

In order to add Assigned to Me, you can try the steps below:

1. Open the home page in the browser and click Site Actions>Edit Page.
2. Choose to insert a web part on the page. Insert the Tasks list
   on the home page.
3. Edit the web part, choose the My Tasks in the Selected View drop
   down,  In this way only the Tasks assigned to current user will show
   up on home page. This can be achieved using a filter **Assigned By is equal to [me].**

Answer (score 0):

The views in the task list is where you can set **Assigned to** field to use the **[Me]** filter to only show tasks assigned to the current user. I believe there is a built in view called "My Tasks" that has this set up for you.

See filter on current user: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-filtering-to-modify-a-SharePoint-view-3D8EFC52-0808-4731-8F9B-3DFAEACEA3D4